# "Scan now to download" QR code for iPhone App Download

Tags: ios, app-store, qr-code

I have recently heard of and ran across QR codes being scanned for app downloads. I would like to know how this works? Can someone explain to me what program they use to "scan" and what happens after that? I would love to implement this into my apps.

[image: Example picture of an website with QR code]

Comment: I always wonder if people are really using these. The mental image of people holding their phone at their screen to scan the qr code to get the app is somehow grotesque.

Comment: One up for me just doing it! It's definitely a funny thing. Its a digital world we live in now so we must accept it. I am pleased to offer this to my clients now that I know it works! Its kind of a selling feature for developers to tell their clients to tell THIER clients.. Just scan and download.

Comment: On Android, this works even a bit better, since you can link straight to the market, with a link like market://search?q=pname:my.package ; I am not sure of an equivalent for iOS but suspect there is one.

Comment: I interpret OP question to be 'is there a baseline tool to scan QR Codes on iOS or does it require a separate app? For example, does iTunes mobile app have a 'scan' function built in? I realize this is an old post but was wondering the same thing as I am an Android user and do not see any better versions of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [QR Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code), (note these are not barcodes, barcodes are the lines) which can be linked to many things such as websites, provide contact information (such as vcard or email etc). Checkout the Link for more information.

You can create QR Codes using programs or [online tools](http://qrcode.kaywa.com/) . You basically setup your QR-Code then when a person uses a program that can read the QR-code, it does the corresponding task.

So if I wanted to provide a QR code for my iPhone app, I would just create a QR-code for the URL to my app from the App Store. Then when a user scans that on the iPhone it would open the iTunes program to my exact app.

Answer (score 0):

artljoe is right. You can use the link of the app from the App Store to create a QR code.

In fact, you can create a universal link to promote downloads with QR codes. With the universal link, when someone scans the QR code, they will be taken to their respective app store. You can read more about it here: https://www.beaconstac.com/app-download-qr-code